# R variable correlation

Tags: r

For this dataset, the value from baseline:t3 is the tumor size, and I want to look at the relationship between one subject's tumor size change and PCR value (PCR=0 means there are still active cancer cells, and PCR = 1 means cancer cells are gone).

Basically I want to see if there is any correlation between tumor size change and PCR value.

Thanks for help!

```
SUBJECTID   Baseline   t1   t2  t3  PCR

1001        88          78  30  14  0
1002        29          26  66  16  0
1003        50          64  54  46  0
1004        91          90  99  43  0
1005        98          109 60  42  0
1007        100         100     54  0
1008        45          49  47  32  0
1009        75          66  57  7   0
1010        60          52  20  3   1
1011        68          68  56  47  1
1012        78          84  56  57  0
1013        71          70  8   5   0
1015        79          50  11  3   1
1016        73          60  57  36  0
1017        54          27  16      0
1018        50          37  33  26  0
1019        115         68  33  67  0
1021        63          55  0   0   1
1022        98          91  76  75  0
1024        76          76      0   0
1025        47          45  42  42
1026        32          25  14  0   1
1027        40          37  65      0
1028        60          110 110 0   0
```

Comment: Take a look https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a t-test would suffice. Needed to make several extra data entries because of your ragged data:

```
dput(dfrm)
structure(list(SUBJECTID = c(1001L, 1002L, 1003L, 1004L, 1005L, 
1007L, 1008L, 1009L, 1010L, 1011L, 1012L, 1013L, 1015L, 1016L, 
1017L, 1018L, 1019L, 1021L, 1022L, 1024L, 1025L, 1026L, 1027L, 
1028L), Baseline = c(88L, 29L, 50L, 91L, 98L, 100L, 45L, 75L, 
60L, 68L, 78L, 71L, 79L, 73L, 54L, 50L, 115L, 63L, 98L, 76L, 
47L, 32L, 40L, 60L), t1 = c(78L, 26L, 64L, 90L, 109L, 100L, 49L, 
66L, 52L, 68L, 84L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 27L, 37L, 68L, 55L, 91L, 76L, 
45L, 25L, 37L, 110L), t2 = c(30L, 66L, 54L, 99L, 60L, NA, 47L, 
57L, 20L, 56L, 56L, 8L, 11L, 57L, 16L, 33L, 33L, 0L, 76L, 76L, 
42L, 14L, 65L, 110L), t3 = c(14L, 16L, 46L, 43L, 42L, 54L, 32L, 
7L, 3L, 47L, 57L, 5L, 3L, 36L, NA, 26L, 67L, 0L, 75L, 0L, 42L, 
0L, NA, 0L), PCR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("SUBJECTID", 
"Baseline", "t1", "t2", "t3", "PCR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))


> t.test(dfrm$t3[dfrm$PCR==0], dfrm$t3[dfrm$PCR==1] )

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  dfrm$t3[dfrm$PCR == 0] and dfrm$t3[dfrm$PCR == 1]
t = 2.0916, df = 7.3971, p-value = 0.07267
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.658325 47.575972
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 33.05882  10.60000
```

It's not really a "correlation" but rather a two-group comparison of mean sizes in the two groups defined by PCR.